# How to delete record found by a left join

Tags: mysql, sql

With following query I can find the data I want to delete:

```
SELECT ab.id, ab.anlage_id, a.id
FROM `anlagetobedienung` AS ab
LEFT JOIN anlage_new AS a ON ab.`anlage_id` = a.id
WHERE a.id IS NULL
```

How do I have to write the DELETE statement that deletes the found records in the anlagetobedienung table?

Comment: found records in `anlage_new`? Your query specifically asks for rows in `anlagetobedienung` for which there is **no row** in `anlage_new`. Do you rather want to delete from `anlagetobedienung`?

Comment: You are right it should be anlagetobedienung. Corrected the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE ab
FROM `anlagetobedienung` AS ab 
LEFT JOIN anlage_new AS a ON ab.`anlage_id` = a.id 
WHERE a.id IS NULL
```

Comment: That's what I tried. I got #1109 - Unknown table 'anlagetobedienung' in MULTI DELETE, which isn't a typo problem.

Comment: @BetaRide: The table name has been aliased. Try replacing `delete anlagetobedienung` with `delete ab`

Comment: @Andomar : Thanks for fixing the query!

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'd say:

```
delete anlage_new 
where id in (
    SELECT  a.id
    FROM `anlagetobedienung` AS ab
    LEFT JOIN anlage_new AS a ON ab.`anlage_id` = a.id
    WHERE a.id IS NULL
)
```

i.e. you delete the rows where the primary key is in the result of the select that identifies the records to delete.

But according to your query those have `id = NULL` which doesn't seem to make any sense.

Can you provide some example data?

After your edit, I'd say this should work:

```
delete `anlagetobedienung` 
where id in (
    SELECT  ab.id
    FROM `anlagetobedienung` AS ab
    LEFT JOIN anlage_new AS a ON ab.`anlage_id` = a.id
    WHERE a.id IS NULL
)
```

Note: the inner select has 'ab.id' instead 'a.id' which seems to be the only column in the original select that has a chance of containing something useful.

Comment: so : `delete anlage_new where id is null`?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM anlagebedienung aDEL WHERE aDEL.id IN 
 (SELECT ab.id 
  FROM `anlagetobedienung` AS ab
  LEFT JOIN anlage_new AS a ON ab.`anlage_id` = a.id
  WHERE a.id IS NULL )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's what I tried already before. The result is: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'aDEL WHERE aDEL.id IN (SELECT ab.id FROM `anlagetobedienung` AS ab LEFT J' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
DELETE FROM anlagetobedienung A
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM anlage_new AN WHERE AN.id = A.anlage_id)
```

If MySQL supports aliases in a `DELETE FROM` (supported in MS SQL, but I know that some of the major RDBMS's don't support this) then you could do:

```
DELETE ab
FROM
    anlagetobedienung AS ab
LEFT JOIN anlage_new AS a ON
    ab.anlage_id = a.id
WHERE
    a.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
DELETE FROM anlagetobedienung ab
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM anlage_new a
                    WHERE a.id = ab.anlage_id
                  )
```